# How can I clear the previous output of a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Every time I run the function it shows all the previous outputs as well. How can I fix this to only show the output for the variable that I just passed to the function

```
def take_median(var):
temp = df.groupby(['Outcome'])[[var]].median().reset_index()
return temp
```

See this screenshot for first time I run the function

[image: See this screenshot for first time I run the function]

This is for the second time

[image: This is for the second time]

For the third time

[image: For the third time]

Comment: Try running the cell with function definition before running the function again.

Comment: tried it but it's doing the same thing